# Docker jenkins access port

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, port

I am running docker compose of jenkins image by command `docker-compose up` my config files 
Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:openjdk-8-jre

EXPOSE 50000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'

services:    
    jenkins:
        image: jenkins:2.60.3-alpine                 
        ports:
        - 50000:50000
```

My container runs docker ps result:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
7dbe18cdbb53        jenkins:2.60.3-alpine   "/bin/tini -- /usr/l…"   22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes       8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50000->50000/tcp   docker_jenkins_1
```

I checked the docker host by `docker inspect 7dbe18cdbb53`
Result:

```
],
                "NetworkID": "e3a5461960939397615620f051696f8b78fde9352d0c8b42b4ed679a1e847b9b",
                "EndpointID": "999b5d3525b2fe823c5ed0033bb27e85b3ca26356b4bd9f1525de005739fecde",
                "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null

`
```

When i try to access from browser like 172.18.0.2:50000 it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

The `jenkins` image that you have is configured to listen http traffic on port `8080`.
Have a look at this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/c2d6f2122fa03c437e139a317b7fe5b9547fe49e/Dockerfile

This is the part where the http port default value is defined

> ARG http_port=8080

and this is where it is exposed

> # for main web interface:
>
> EXPOSE ${http_port}

Similarly you can find that (slave) Agent port is `50000`.

In your `docker ps` output you can see that the jenkins container is listening on `8080` but this is not publish on the host.
So basically you are trying to connect via http to the agent port and it is not working as expected. 
Do change the docker compose file to also publish the `8080` port and use that.